# pre-defined constants for non-trivial data types

Tags: c#, constants, readonly, mutable

My Goal: Create a C# class for predefined errors that have both an ID and a Message.
Here was what I tried:

```
public class MyError
{
    public static readonly MyError OK = new MyError(0, "OK");
    public static readonly MyError Bad = new MyError(1, "Bad Stuff");

    public MyError(int id, string message)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Message = message;
    }

    public readonly int Id;
    public readonly string Message;
}
```

This compiles just fine and I am sure it would work just fine in practice. But I always like to follow Code Analysis guidelines. In the above case, CA2104 is violated "Do not declare read only mutable reference types"

I have tried a number of things other than the above, including trying const instead of readonly (won't even compile), { get; private set; } for member access, struct instead of class, etc.

Which is the mutable type? Id or Message?

I'm open to any suggestions that accomplish what I want: Pre-defined constants for non-trivial data types.

Of course, I can always just ignore the warning but I have found that there is usually a reason for them.

*** CLARIFICATION ***
My question is really less about this specific MyError class and more about a more fundamental problem of defining constants for stuff other than basic data types.

Suppose I want to define three constants that are doubles. C# lets me do this like so:

```
   public const double HighValue = 11.0;
   public const double LowValue = 0.1;
   public const double MidValue = 5.5;
```

C# creates a small handful of useful constants for *double* pre-defined for us: *NaN*, *MinValue*, *MaxValue*, *NegativeInfinity*, *PositiveInfinity*.

So now, what if *I* want to pre-define some interesting constants for three-dimensional vectors (X,Y,Z) in space? I can define constants for doubles, integers, strings, etc. but how do I define a constant for something less trivial? The Origin is an interesting constant I want to give a name to:

```
public class Vector3D
{
    /// The problem is that this does not work
    public const Vector3D Origin = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };

    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;
}
```

I'm not going to need thousands of constants. Just a few like our friend *double* has with *NaN*, etc. The class doesn't need to be especially protected or sealed either. Anybody is free to create Vector3D objects and derive from it in any way they want. I just want to have a special constant named Origin that has value (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

Comment: Are you *sure* this example is representative of your class? You don't have any other properties? (I would personally suggest making these properties rather than public fields, by the way.) Also, consider sealing your class - which prevent mutable derived classes from being created.

Comment: @JonSkeet: AFAIK, the CA rule cannot recognize immutability.

Comment: @SLaks: That's a pity - especially as the error message specifically talks about mutable reference types, *implying* it can recognize immutable ones :(

Comment: the way the class has been design to return error code & msg is not good. suppose if i have 100 predefined err code & msg then i have to create 100 static instance inside the class. this idea is bogus. lot better way people can handle like put the predefine error in xml file and load data from that file when apps start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type is not mutable, but Code Analysis doesn't know that.
This warning is a false positive; you should suppress it.

---

To answer your edited question:

`const` can only be applied to primitives.
For custom types, `static readonly` is the only option.

As long as the type is properly immutable, it will work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. I am marking this as the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The type is not mutable.  The Code Analysis gets confused by having public readonly fields.

You can fix the code analysis issue by making your public fields public properties:

```
public MyError(int id, string message)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.message = message;
}
private readonly int id;
private readonly string message;
public int Id { get { return id; } }
public string Message { get { return message; } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your properties should not be static because every instance of this class will have their own ID and Message, do you agree?

Comment: Those properties aren't static; you're misunderstanding his code.  Also, this isn't an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class that

- is **sealed**, to prevent it from being inherited
- has a **private constructor**, to prevent it from being instantiated from outside of the class
- provides properties with **private setters**, so they cannot be set from outside.

That would give you the following code:

```
public sealed class MyError
{
    public static readonly MyError OK = new MyError(0, "OK");

    public static readonly MyError Bad = new MyError(1, "Bad Stuff");

    private MyError(int id, string message)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Message = message;
    }

    public int ID { get; private set; }

    public string Message { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: people can not create instance and can not inherit. so i just do not understand how people use this class from out side. what kind of purpose it solve? anyone can explain...i just keen to know. thanks

Comment: They don't need to inherit or instanicate the class themselves. The just use the values provided by `MyError.OK` and `MyError.Bad`. These two static properties provide instances of the class. The only two immutable instances that will ever exist.

Comment: i have seen only 2 properties have been declared public not static.only two instance of same class has been declared as static?

Comment: the way the class has been design to return error code & msg is not good. suppose if i have 100 predefined err code & msg then i have to create 100 static instance inside the class. this idea is bogus. lot better way people can handle like put the predefine error in xml file and load data from that file when apps start.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I plan to add some clarification by editing my question to add more detail.